# NoSql Battle - Survivors?

Tags: java, database, performance, nosql, scalability

GraphDB vs Key-ValueDb's

Neo4j versus OrientDB
Valdemort versus OrientKV

Features to choice and compare

- Easy to install (no dependencies, just place/extract on folder)
- Performance and scalability
- small footprint
- good documentation (tutorials and examples)
- administration facilities, monitoring tools
- low learning curve
- interface with java or ruby

What are the winners?

Another option with the same characteristics/features?

Comment: Or fleetdb looks like an easy solution. But it might be missing some features you are looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the winner that you are looking for. From my experience, the ideal type of databse is the one which is best for your application. For advanced application, you may want to have object binding to database. The best option of all is still relational database like SQL. It has been developed for more than 20 years. Tools are available for SQL everywhere. NoSql database is still young and tools are difficult to find.

I personally have a try with Neo4j. I love the graph model they use in Neo4j. It allows you to add attributes to node and relationships. However, tools for viewing the graph or NoSQL databse are not nearly as good as SQL table.

For me, I find plain text file or xml is the best database for most of my application.

Answer (score 2):

What about document databases? I think mongo is the greatest thing ever

Comment: mongodb is good although I prefer redis. I also think he wants java solutions(neo4j/orientdb/voldemort/orientkv all are java solutions).

Comment: Wrong!  According to Google, the **greatest thing ever** is the Muppets version of Bohemian Rhapsody; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgbNymZ7vqY

Comment: @alfred: redis is a key value store, which is as close to a document database as it is to a relational database. @Stephen C: I stand corrected.

Comment: OrientDB is a document-graph database, so has all the features of document databases like MongoDB

Comment: @Lvca: Cool :) ill check it out

Answer (score 2):

I'm with Steve C. The Muppets win! Actually, I'm evaluating Neo4j and OrientDB. Leaning to OrientDB because it's performance profile matches what I need.

Rather than look at the "bling" figure out what the read/write ratio will be for your system. Is it more read than write, or are searches more important? Once you've figured that out, then the selection becomes easier.

BTW Both Neo4j and OrientDB have good documentation and examples. All the best with your choice.

Comment: could you please share your experience with OrientDB so far ? Im evaluating it myself and would greatly appreciate any feedback from real use.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference I would say is - scalability. Neo4j doesn't support the **cluster** as of now. But you can have master slave replication. However OrientDB support cluster.

The data at each node needs to be stored as **key-value pairs** in Neo4j. With OrientDB you can save data as **document** and can still have graph like relationships. OriendDB also supports ACID.